.bat file configuration for raspberry pi 4B Qemu for raspian os 64bit bookworm (latest qemu emulation)
i want the content of run.bat file required for running latest raspian os 64bit bookworm (raspberry Pi 4B) on qemu(aarch64) on windows 11. I had seen earlier version but they are no help as thery arm1176 but Now we have cortex-a72 with 2G minimum (instead of 256) as shown in many other places and website, I tried changing cpu to cortex-a72 and memory to 2G but got error like guest not initialized as well as if this error is fixed my raspberry Pi qemu wouldn't open. All other Version are older shown on internet so if anyone can tell me the way to run it i.e the run.bat file configuration I will be greatful. If you need kernel and dtb file then you can look it into it via poweriso Or ultraiso after extracting .img.xz file to .img as online a github link was given but is of older version so will not work.
P. S: I once tried raspberry 3B+ on bullseye.img  but there I got stuck with   login username and password part, although online it shows that use "pi" As login name and "raspberry" As password but it gives error/incorrect password so if anyone can help with this too then I will be greatful.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
